# Opening Image File gives error in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-gallery

I am trying to open a jpg image file in gallery. This gives a error. I am using the code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/image123.jpg"),"image/jpeg");
startActivityForResult(intent, 900);
```

This gives a option to open file in gallery. I select Gallery from the list. But it does not open up. I use ASTRO file manager and open the same image file. It opens up fine now. Please let me know if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you got `/mnt/sdcard`. Try [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) instead.

Comment: I am actually using this Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to get the path. How ever when i add "file://" prefix as "file://mnt/sdcard" things start to work... but I am not sure if i can hard code this file://.... will this work in all systems of android? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Specified Image Path? You can't.
 Please Refer My Question as [How to access different File Manager specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883502/how-to-access-different-file-manager-specific-path-in-android). Refer this link and then you got a answer.