# How to access different File Manager specific path in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have installed different types of File Manager. The different Types of File Managers are

1. Default File Manager
2. ASTRO-File-Manager-v3.1.342.apk(Astro)
3. FileManager-1.2.apk(OI File Manager)
4. Root-Browser-File-Manager-v1.4.0.apk(Root Browser)

Code :

```
File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Pictures");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:/"+filePath.getAbsolutePath()), "file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

When I can select `Astro File Manager`, `Root Browser`, `Default File Manager` I got the location path as `/mnt/sdcard`.

But when I access the `OI File Manager` I got the location path as `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures`.

How do get and open to different types of File Manager to access the location path as `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures`

Comment: `private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;`

Comment: Can you Please help me some one. How do Open this path `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures` directly using the File Manager as `Astro File Manager`, `Root Browser`, `OI File Manager` and also `Default File Manager`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying initial path to a file explorer? You can't.

Read documentation for [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). The contract for using this action doesn't specify initial location at all. So various file managers do different things, and it's all legal and correct. Some use the data you try to input, some use last directory where user was, some start at root of sdcard.

Btw, your mime type "file/*" looks like nonsense, there's no such known mime type. Just use "*/*" to match all files.

Comment: Mice Thanks for reply. May i directly access to internal memory and/or external memory. My Android Mobile Internal Memory path is /mnt/sdcard and External Memory path is /mnt/extsdcard. May I directly access to internal/external memory path. Is this possible?

Comment: You can read/write in device's mass memory (internal or external) without problem. You may need permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Mice Thank You. Your explanation is useful to me. Can you post any one example/part of code here. How do access the mass memory both internal and external. Where I can change the path of internal and external memory. Guide me. Thanks.

Comment: You should write new question for that, it's rather different topic than what you originally asked.